# How can I get InternetGatewayId of an existing AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

Background: We have an VPC, it has an Internet Gateway attached.

I would like to get the InternetGatewayId of the VPC via aws-cdk

```golang
vpc := awsec2.Vpc_FromLookup(stack, jsii.String(viper.GetString(`vpc.id`)), &awsec2.VpcLookupOptions{
        VpcId: jsii.String(viper.GetString(`vpc.id`)),
    }) //Here it returns awsec2.Ivpc
```

But according to the code, only `awsec2.Vpc` has a method `InternetGatewayId()`. How could I convert `awsec2.Ivpc` to `awsec2.Vpc`?

Comment: How was the VPC created?

Comment: @fedonev manually

Answer (score 1):

The `Ivpc` type returned from `Vpc_FromLookup` is a [CDK convenience method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#importing-an-existing-vpc) to cache a limited set of VPC attributes at synth-time.   Unfortunately, the [Internet Gateway ID isn't one of them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#accessing-the-internet-gateway):

> Currently you're unable to get the [Internet Gateway] ID for imported VPCs. To do that you'd have to specifically look up the Internet Gateway by name, which would require knowing the name beforehand.

A simple, deterministic workaround is to manually store the ID as a [SSM Parameter Store Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html). At synth-time, `StringParameter_ValueFromLookup` looks up and caches the IGW ID value as [Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html) in `cdk.context.json`.:

```golang
igwID := awsssm.StringParameter_ValueFromLookup(stack, jsii.String("/my-params/vpc/igw-id"))
```

A more advanced CDK-only solution is to lookup the ID in a deploy-time [CustomResource](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2#readme-custom-resources), which *"can do arbitrary lookups or modifications during a CloudFormation deployment"* (typically by making SDK calls using a Lambda).  Note that this is not necessarily a better solution, because it [introduces non-determinacy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps) into the deployment.